# mysql select statement bring back column if column is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Is there a way to `select col1 if col2 is empty` `else use col2`? `col1` will never be empty.

```
select 
ug.permissions,
g.name,
g.display,
g.permissions
from system.users_groups as ug
inner join system.groups as g on ug.group_id = g.id
where ug.user_id = ?
```

The above statement brings back both permissions columns, I would like to bring back only one permissions column.

`if ug.permissions = '' then use g.permissions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using COALESCE and NULLIF:**

```
select 
COALESCE(NULLIF(ug.permissions,''),g.permissions) as permissions ,
g.name,
g.display
from system.users_groups as ug
inner join system.groups as g on ug.group_id = g.id
where ug.user_id = ?
```

**Using CASE:**

```
select 
CASE WHEN ug.permissions = '' OR ug.permissions IS NULL
THEN
     g.permissions
ELSE
     ug.permissions 
END as permissions ,
g.name,
g.display
from system.users_groups as ug
inner join system.groups as g on ug.group_id = g.id
where ug.user_id = ?
```

Comment: I used the CASE version